# The total sampling time stays unchanged, and the impact of reducing the sampling rate and number of samples on FFT

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

There is a time series X(t) with total times T, sample rate *f*s, and sample number N=*f*s*T. I used FFT in matlab *your text*and get the results:
[The result is as I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK3X6.png)

In order to reduce the calculation amount of post-processing, I used this code "xx=x(1:n:end)" to reduce the sample number N by n times, but the total times T is unchanged (the *f*s is reduced by n times). Then I get this results:
[n=50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNCjX.png)

I don't understand why there are new signals around 7.6 GHz (6 GHz). The total time T is unchanged, so the frequency resolution does not change. I'm not sure if this phenomenon is spectrum leakage. The reduced *f*s should make impact of bandwidth, but the new sampling rate still satisfies the Nyquist sampling theorem.

Then I try to use different n. When n=110, the results like correct:
[n=110](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsYKI.png)

There are many explains about the impact of sample time T and sample rate *f*s. But in this case, the sample number N is too large, and I need to reduce it with sample time T unchanged. However, the results of FFT with different scale n are too different, especially the later impact of this non-existent frequency signal is unknown.

Comment: “the new sampling rate still satisfies the Nyquist sampling theorem” — no, it doesn’t, because the spectrum is not 0 in the regions excluded by the sampling. I assume your y axis is decibel, so it’s very small there, and so the amount of aliasing should be small, but it’s not 0.

Comment: I’m guessing the “signal” you see is rounding errors, noise. Try plotting the actual values, not the logarithm, and you won’t see any of that any more.

Comment: So you are trying to reduce the number of samples (decimation) in order to optimize post processing. The way you are doing it by just throwing away samples with any further processing will most likely introduce aliasing. Instead you should first lowpass filter your signal and then decimate it. There are plenty of ways to do so, but a good starting point in the context of matlab is [decimate](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html)

Comment: For some theoretical background have a look at [Multirate Systems](https://sps.ewi.tudelft.nl/Education/courses/ee2s31/slides/DSP8.pdf)

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thx for your reply. The initial sampling rate bandwidth supports 5 THz. So, I thought that the Nyquist sampling theorem is still satisfied even if the sampling rate is reduced by 100 times.  This series x(t) is measured from the spectrum and using "dBm" as the y-axis unit is an expected behavior. I also tried to use the linear unit (mW/W), and it is small as you say. But I don't know why the results of n=110 are better than n=50.  I also tried to use this code P（P<1e-6）=1e-12 to remove these signals at the linear axis, but it wasn't useful and made damage in the spectrum.

Comment: @Irreducible, thx for your help! At the moment, it is useful. I probably know the reason. This signal contains a lot of high-frequency components (>6 GHz). Just using a downsample would lead to aliasing.